# `data.table::unique` errors: is not an exported object from namespace

Tags: r, package, data.table

`help(unique)` shows that `unique` function is present in two packages - `base` and `data.table`. I would like to use this function from `data.table` package. I thought that the following syntax - `data <- data.table::unique(data)` indicates the package to be used. But I get the following error -

> 'unique' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'

But `data <- unique(data)` works well.

What is wrong here?

Comment: `data.table:::unique.data.table(data)` it's not exported and there is not `unique`, just `unique.data.table`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function in question is really `unique.data.table`, an S3 method defined in the `data.table` package.  That method is not really intended to be called directly, so it isn't exported.  This is typically the case with S3 methods.  Instead, the package registers the method as an S3 method, which then allows the S3 generic, `base::unique` in this case, to dispatch on it.  So the right way to call the function is:

```
library(data.table)
irisDT <- data.table(iris)
unique(irisDT)
```

We use `base::unique`, which is exported, and it dispatches `data.table:::unique.data.table`, which is not exported.  The function `data.table:::unique` does not actually exist (or does it need to).

As eddi points out, `base::unique` dispatches based on the class of the object called.  So `base::unique` will call `data.table:::unique.data.table` only if the object is a `data.table`.  You can force a call to that method directly with something like `data.table:::unique.data.table(iris)`, but internally that will mostly likely result in the next method getting called unless your object is actually a `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand your answer correctly - if argument passed to `unique` is `data.frame`, then `unique` from the `base` package is used; if `data.table` is passed - then from `data.table`?

Comment: @LA_ yes (`unique.data.frame` will be used), and take a look at source code of `unique` (by simply typing `unique`) and then read `?UseMethod`

Comment: It's important to understand that this is only true for "S3 methods". (R is an evolving language.) Different procedures are needed for S4 and later sorts of classes.

Answer (score 7):

There are actually two infix operators in R that pull functions from particular package namespaces. You used `::` but there is also a `:::` that retrieves "unexported" functions. The `unique`-function is actually a family of functions and its behavior will depend on both the class of its argument and the particular packages that have been loaded. The R term of this is "generic". Try:

```
data <- data.table:::unique(data)  # assuming 'data' is a data.table
```

The other tool that lets you peek behind the curtain that the lack of "exportation" is creating is the `getAnywhere`-function. It lets you see the code at the console:

```
> unique.data.table
Error: object 'unique.data.table' not found

> getAnywhere(unique.data.table)
A single object matching ‘unique.data.table’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for unique from namespace data.table
  namespace:data.table
with value

function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, by = key(x), 
    ...) 
{
    if (!cedta()) 
        return(NextMethod("unique"))
    dups <- duplicated.data.table(x, incomparables, fromLast, 
        by, ...)
    .Call(CsubsetDT, x, which_(dups, FALSE), seq_len(ncol(x)))
}
<bytecode: 0x2ff645950>
<environment: namespace:data.table>
```