# I cannot find unique function from data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

I am a beginner in R and also new to `data.table` package, and have been using it to perform computation-intensive applications. So far, it's been a great experience.

I was reading the latest `data.table` package release notes at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf , and found that data.table has a `unique()` (Page 32 of the PDF above) as well. However, I am unable to find this function in data.table package. I found `uniqueN`. I couldn't even find `duplicated()`. I am not sure why this is the case.

I also found  thread that talks about `unique()` from data.table package. I am assuming that they are not using unique() from base R.

Here's my `SessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices datasets  stats     graphics  grid      tcltk     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Hmisc_4.0-2             Formula_1.2-1           survival_2.40-1         magrittr_1.5           
 [5] stringr_1.1.0           bit64_0.9-5             bit_1.1-12              tufterhandout_1.2.1    
 [9] knitr_1.15.1            rmarkdown_1.3           tufte_0.2               corrplot_0.77          
[13] purrr_0.2.2             readr_1.0.0             tibble_1.2              tidyverse_1.0.0        
[17] cowplot_0.7.0           plotly_4.5.6            ggplot2_2.2.1           maps_3.1.1             
[21] directlabels_2015.12.16 tidyr_0.6.1             ggthemes_3.3.0          R2HTML_2.3.2           
[25] lubridate_1.6.0         xts_0.9-7               zoo_1.7-14              lattice_0.20-34        
[29] corrgram_1.10           hexbin_1.27.1           sm_2.2-5.4              compare_0.2-6          
[33] installr_0.18.0         psych_1.6.12            reshape2_1.4.2          readstata13_0.8.5      
[37] pastecs_1.3-18          boot_1.3-18             vcd_1.4-3               car_2.1-4              
[41] xlsxjars_0.6.1          rJava_0.9-8             debug_1.3.1             dplyr_0.5.0            
[45] foreign_0.8-67          gmodels_2.16.2          openxlsx_4.0.0          plyr_1.8.4             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] minqa_1.2.4         colorspace_1.3-2    class_7.3-14        modeltools_0.2-21   mclust_5.2.1       
 [6] rprojroot_1.1       htmlTable_1.8       base64enc_0.1-3     MatrixModels_0.4-1  flexmix_2.3-13     
[11] mvtnorm_1.0-5       codetools_0.2-15    splines_3.3.2       mnormt_1.5-5        robustbase_0.92-7  
[16] jsonlite_1.2        nloptr_1.0.4        pbkrtest_0.4-6      cluster_2.0.5       kernlab_0.9-25     
[21] httr_1.2.1          backports_1.0.4     assertthat_0.1      Matrix_1.2-7.1      lazyeval_0.2.0     
[26] acepack_1.4.1       htmltools_0.3.5     quantreg_5.29       tools_3.3.2         gtable_0.2.0       
[31] Rcpp_0.12.8         trimcluster_0.1-2   gdata_2.17.0        nlme_3.1-128        iterators_1.0.8    
[36] fpc_2.1-10          lmtest_0.9-34       lme4_1.1-12         gtools_3.5.0        dendextend_1.3.0   
[41] DEoptimR_1.0-8      MASS_7.3-45         scales_0.4.1        TSP_1.1-4           parallel_3.3.2     
[46] SparseM_1.74        RColorBrewer_1.1-2  gridExtra_2.2.1     rpart_4.1-10        latticeExtra_0.6-28
[51] stringi_1.1.2       gclus_1.3.1         mvbutils_2.7.4.1    foreach_1.4.3       checkmate_1.8.2    
[56] seriation_1.2-1     caTools_1.17.1      prabclus_2.2-6      bitops_1.0-6        evaluate_0.10      
[61] htmlwidgets_0.8     R6_2.2.0            gplots_3.0.1        DBI_0.5-1           whisker_0.3-2      
[66] mgcv_1.8-16         nnet_7.3-12         KernSmooth_2.23-15  data.table_1.10.0   digest_0.6.11      
[71] diptest_0.75-7      stats4_3.3.2        munsell_0.4.3       registry_0.3        viridisLite_0.1.3  
[76] quadprog_1.5-5
```

I also went through [Data table error could not find function "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513319/data-table-error-could-not-find-function) thread, ran the command `install.packages("data.table", type="source", dependencies=TRUE)`, but nothing happened.

To clarify, when I say I am unable to find, here's what happens:

**First issue:** When I type data.table:: on RStudio, it automatically populates all functions, but it doesn't show me `data.table::unique` or even `data.table::duplicated`.

**Second issue:** Even if I assume that RStudio is having some issues, if I call `data.table::unique` or even `data.table:::unique.data.table`, I get the error message saying, `Error: 'unique' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'.`

I'd sincerely appreciate any thoughts and help.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't find it? What did you do in order to use it? Did it throw an error? Did you look for it using some code? In your `sessionInfo` data.table is not attached.

Comment: You mean `data.table:::unique.data.table`?

Comment: @LyzandeR and lukeA - I have clarified what is happening above so that all readers know what's going on. Thanks for your willingness to help me.

Comment: Explanation might be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372972/why-data-tableunique-doesnt-work).