# Performance of unique in base vs data.table

Tags: r, data.table, unique

I have a fairly large data set (4.7M rows and 42 variables). When I try to save this to the shared drive I'm working on with `saveRDS` Windows throws an error message, but smaller data sets save with no issue. To respond to this issue I decided to normalize my data and save the relevant dimension and fact data.

After extracting the columns defining one dimension of the data my next step was to remove duplication in the dimension with `unique`, but executing

```
dim_data <- unique(dim_data)
```

caused my session to hang for quite a long time before returning with the error message

> Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
>
> Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 127.6 Mb

(my machine has 16 GB of RAM).

I wrestled with this for a while before trying

```
dim_data <- as.data.table(dim_data)
dim_data <- unique(dim_data)
```

At which point the second line executed instantly and successfully.

I'm happy to have a solution, and I understand that a different version of `unique` is called [depending on the class of its argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374433/1393860), but what accounts for the inability of `unique` to even complete its computation when applied to data frames which exceed a certain size? Is the base implementation extremely inefficient, and if so is this known and planned for a fix (I couldn't find anything about the performance of `unique`)? Conversely, is it less about the data.table implementation of the function and more about data.table objects being stored more intelligently behind the scenes?

Comment: Have you searched for how to handle memory issues in R.

Comment: @42- I have, yes, and I employ various mitigating techniques to the best of my ability. I haven't found anything which might explain this difference in performance however. Are there resources which explain this that I might have missed?

Comment: @42- The memory issues I'm encountering are really secondary though, aren't they?  Clearly something is different about `unique` applied to `data.table`s as opposed to `data.frame`s, and that is what the question is about. The system configuration should be irrelevant except to the extent that it alters this difference no? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are welcome to ignore the advice offered here. System configuration is NOT irrelevant. Windows is notoriously less efficient than Nix OSes.

Comment: @42- I'm definitely not disputing the inefficiencies of Windows, but even if I'm working with a massively inefficient architecture made of wooden tubes and rolling balls the question of why `unique` has such different behavior with respect to `data.frame` and `data.table` *on that same system*  would remain. Not looking to ignore any advice, and do appreciate it, just don't see the connection to my actual question. I'm also happy to add any specific details that would help to answer the question.